# Java count words repeated in string

Tags: java, string, split

I Know this quetion has been asked quite few times already but I have a twist.

I have a below string and I wan to check the count how many times given word is repeated in the string.

```
String randomText = "AbDdfSwapnilswapniljsdncdsbswapnil"
```

How to count the word `"swapnil"` is repeated?

Comment: What's the twist?

Comment: most of post having `string.split(" ")` answer but it is not applicable here.

Comment: Why not? Anyway, there are plenty of other (and better) solutions.

Comment: Put is in answer buddy

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String randomText = "AbDdfSwapnilswapniljsdncdsbswapnil";

        String text = "swapnil";
        int times = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomText.length(); i++) {
            if (randomText.substring(i).startsWith(text)) {
                times ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(randomText + " contains " + text + " " + times + " times");
}
```

Comment: there is probably a better way tho

Comment: What if you search for `"aa"` inside `"aaa"`?